# Amazon s3 404 pages are cached on cloudflare cdn

Tags: caching, amazon-s3, http-status-code-404, cloudflare

I am using cloudflare dns subdomain which is pointing to amazon s3 bucket. The problem I am facing is cloudflare cache 404 response from amazon s3. Even I upload image to amazon s3 , cloudflare always response in 404 because the previous response is cached . I want to use cloudflare cache because of performace reasons but I don't want to manually clear cloudflare cache for 404 urls.
It is obvious that if amazon s3 is responding with 404 then it is no use to cache that url.

May be I am skipping some cloudflare setting which do this.

Comment: did u find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

CloudFlare actually caches 404s for about ten minutes (lightens the potential load on your server). Have you looked at purging your cache as one workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem not only for S3, but for web server responses.

Seems like the solution they give is to add a no-cache header on the server response for 404s.